# Study L-function associated to elliptic curves

Tags: representation-theory, elliptic-curves, l-functions

I'm studying Iwasawa theory, and now I'm reading Greenberg's article about the application of Iwasawa theory of elliptic curves, but I have some problems on the first chapter, because it's about Hasse Weil L-functions and p-adic L-functions. Can someone suggest me a book or notes to study these topics? Thanks!

Comment: Search about Galois representations, Hecke and Artin L-functions, L-function of CM elliptic curves, and try [Milne](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Milne+J.S.+Elliptic+curves+and+algebraic+geometry.+Math679+U+Michigan+notes+(draft+1996)(163s).pdf) and [Silverman ATAEC](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Silverman%2C+Advanced+Topics+in+the+Arithmetic+of+Elliptic+Curves+pdf)